# Adobe Extendscript Toolkit: Illustrator and Intellisense

Tags: adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm using Illustrator CC 2015 and ExtendScript Toolkit 4.5.5. I'm scripting in javascript and intellisense/auto completion is not working.  I've selected the target application as Adobe Illustrator CC 2015, as well as enable auto complete in Edit/Preferences/Help. Is anyone able to replicate this issue? Any thoughts on why it's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, here's the answer. UX could definitely be improved though :D

[image]